# TypeError: _this.$content is not a function - Nuxt.js Content

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to use Nuxt.js Content in my project.
The problem is that when I try to use $content method in my project the `TypeError: _this.$content is not a function` occurs:

```js
async fetch() {
  this.content = await this.$content('data').fetch()
},
```

I imported the `@nuxt/content` in Nuxt config and in typescript config.

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
export default {
  modules: ['@nuxt/content']
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["@nuxt/types", "@types/node", "@nuxt/content"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Which version of content do you use? The latest requires Nuxt3.

Comment: @kissu I officially love you man. It is working now after changing to ^1. Thank you very much <333

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nuxt content v2 needs Nuxt3. If you're using Nuxt2, you should use the v1.

As stated at the end of this page: https://content.nuxtjs.org/get-started#render-pages