# TypeError: $content is not a function - Nuxt-content

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

4

I am trying to use Nuxt.js Content in my project. The problem is that when I try to use $content method in my project the TypeError: _this.$content is not a function occurs:

I am using nuxt 2 and installed the nuxt-content version 1 then also it is giving the error.

can anyone help.

```
<template>
    <v-container>
      <nuxt-content :document="article"/>
    </v-container>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  export default {
    async asyncData({ $content, params }){
        const article = await $content('articles', params.slug).fetch()
        return { article }
    }
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72836661/typeerror-this-content-is-not-a-function-nuxt-js-content

Comment: Indeed, looks like the same. Mind sharing more details regarding the packages you're using?